SVM Classification of test point between support vector and max margin hyperplane
I want to have a theoretical understanding of how do SVM classify a point that is in between Max margin hyperplane and one of the support vector?
So the test point is beyond the support vector (of one side say +ve side) but didn't touch the hyperplane. Which class will it be assigned to?
I need an explanation.

Your question is not related to programming. You will have better chances getting a decent answer in crossvalidated. Short answer is that if it lies on the positive side of the hyperplane, then it belongs to the positive class
